# Belarus, can unmarried couple stay in one room in Minsk?

Tags: hotels

Can an unmarried couple (one American, one Russian) stay in same hotel room in Minsk? Or is there a hassle?

Comment: Belarus Is pretty Soviet, but not *that* Soviet.

Comment: @ach I don't understand what that means?

Comment: @MichaelHampton in the USSR there were strict rules against unmarried people sharing accommodations, and they still exist in many communist countries.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely ok. Nobody will be checking if you are married or not. It is a post-soviet country, but I do not know any post-soviet country in Europe which will have laws or regulation for unmarried couples.

Comment: Poland. We were not allowed to stay in the same room... Had to get separate ones. This was 2009 though.

Comment: @Sebastian Poland is very catholic, so perhaps some hotel owners won't allow it, although I expect that —especially at larger hotel chains— no one will be bothered. I don't think it had anything to do with being (post) soviet.